# Excel Pivot Table - Showing the highest score as an extra column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is there a way to create an extra column and only show the score of the highest score in a previous column? All this being used in a pivot table

e.g.

```
Jan 01  60  60
Jan 02  25  25
Jan 03  96  96
Jan 04  8   8
Jan 05  34  34
Jan 06  99  99
Jan 07  68  68
Jan 08  33  33
Jan 09  21  21
Jan 10  97  97
Feb 01  68  68
Feb 02  50  50
Feb 03  70  70
Feb 04  95  95
Feb 05  63  63
Feb 06  91  91
Feb 07  59  59
Feb 08  76  76
Feb 09  33  33
Feb 10  50  50
Feb 11  65  65
Feb 12  6   6
```

If i was using the data above, within a pivot table - is there a way to add an extra column onto the pivot table and just show the highest score for e.g. Jan in a new column.

For instance the new column would just show 99 for Jan and 95 for Feb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way.

I used the following data for demonstration:

```
| Month | ID | Score |
|-------|----|-------|
| Jan   | 1  | 60    |
| Jan   | 2  | 25    |
| Jan   | 3  | 96    |
| Jan   | 4  | 8     |
| Jan   | 5  | 34    |
| Jan   | 6  | 99    |
| Jan   | 7  | 68    |
| Jan   | 8  | 33    |
| Jan   | 9  | 21    |
| Jan   | 10 | 97    |
| Feb   | 1  | 68    |
| Feb   | 2  | 50    |
| Feb   | 3  | 70    |
| Feb   | 4  | 95    |
| Feb   | 5  | 63    |
| Feb   | 6  | 91    |
| Feb   | 7  | 59    |
| Feb   | 8  | 76    |
| Feb   | 9  | 33    |
| Feb   | 10 | 50    |
| Feb   | 11 | 65    |
| Feb   | 12 | 6     |
```

Steps are:

1. Create a Pivot Table, put the `Month` and `ID` in the **Rows** field and put the `Score` in the **Values** field;
2. Drag the `Score` to **Values** field again (no need to create a duplicated score column in the source data);
3. Go into the `Value Field Settings` of the second `Score` in the **Values** field, set a **Custom Name** as `Max of Score`, select `MAX` under **Summarize value field by**, and go into `Number Format` to set a custom format `;;;` triple semicolons, then all values in the second `Score` column will "disappear";
4. Highlight the subtotal row of `JAN` and `FEB` to set a number format which will overwrite the previous format set for the second `Score` column in the pivot table.

If you have done the above correctly, you should have something like the following:

[image: Demo]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much

Comment: @kirstysmith589 Glad to help :)